# passing arg2 of 'listFind' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, eclipse, warnings, compiler-warnings

I've got some problem with my function and don't know how to solve this problem, This is my code:

```
ListResult result=listFind(currentLines, compareBasicLines, &linePrototype);  <-here problem
```

compareBasicLines pointer to function

```
int compareBasicLines(ptrLine line1, ptrLine line2){
    COMPARE_NUMBER_STRINGS(line1, line2);
}
```

`COMPARE_NUMBER_STRINGS(line1, line2);` defined in another file

```
#define COMPARE_NUMBER_STRINGS(var1, var2)                              \
                    if(var1 == NULL || var2 == NULL){                   \
                        return 0;                                       \
                    }                                                   \
                    return strcmp(var1->strNumber, var2->strNumber);
```

thanks in advance for everyone

this is what I have, my homework is about ADT, so I don't know what exacly do I have inside listFind

```
/**
 * Searches the list for an element fitting the criteria starting from the
 * current element.
 * Note that you need to call listGetFirst if you wish to search from the start
 * of the list. The search starts from the current element.
 * @param list
 *  The list to search in
 * @param compare
 *  Comparison function to decide if an element in the last is equal to the
 *  target elemnt. This function should return 0 for equal elements
 * @param target
 *  A target element to compare with each element in the list.
 * @return
 *  LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT if list or compare are NULL
 *  LIST_INVALID_CURRENT if the current pointer of the list is in invalid state
 *  LIST_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT if no element was found from the current element until
 *  the end of the list
 *  LIST_SUCCESS an element was found and the current pointer of the list is now
 *  set to this element
 *
 */

ListResult listFind(List list, CompareListElements compare, ListElement target);
```

and one more definition

```
typedef int (*CompareListElements)(ListElement, ListElement);

typedef void* ListElement;
```

Comment: Sorry, but you need to be more specific. What is the problem? Does it fail to compile? Fail to link? What are the error messages?

Comment: passing arg2 of ‘listFind’ from incompatible pointer <- this is the error, I can't even compile it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second argument to `listFind()` is of type `int (*)(ptrLine, ptrLine)`.  That is evidently different from the type of the second parameter in the declaration of `listFind()`.

Without seeing the definition of `listFind()`, it's hard to say what you should do to fix it.